# Discord bot would not reply to messages

Tags: python, discord, bots

I made a discord bot and it did go online but the bot just would not work.

Here is the code:

main.py

```py
from typing import Final 
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from discord import Intents, Client, Message
from responses import get_response

#load token
load_dotenv()
TOKEN: Final[str] = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
# print(TOKEN)

#BOT SETUP

intents: Intents = Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
client: Client = Client(intents=intents)

#message functionality
async def send_message(message: Message, user_message: str) -> None:
    if not user_message:
        print("(Message was empty because intents were not enabled problably)")
        return

    if is_private := user_message[0] ==  '?':
        user_message = user_message[1:]
        
    try: 
        response: str = get_response(user_message)
        await message.author.send(response) if is_private else await message.channel.send(response)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        
#handle bot startup
@client.event
async def on_ready() -> None:
    print(f'{client.user} is now running!!')
    
#handle incoming messages
client.event
async def on_message(message: Message) -> None:
    print("A message was sent")
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    
    username: str = str(message.author)
    user_message: str = message.content
    channel: str = str(message.channel)
    
    print(f'[{channel}] {username}: "{user_message}"')
    await send_message(message, user_message)
    
#main entry point
def main() -> None:
    client.run(token=TOKEN)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

response.py

```py
from random import choice, randint

def get_response(user_input: str) -> str:
    print("function called")
    lowered: str = user_input.lower()
    
    if lowered == '':
        return "Well, you\'re awfully silent..."
    elif 'hello' in lowered:
        return "hello there"
    elif 'roll dice' in lowered:
        return f'You rolled : {randint(1,6)}'
    else:
        return choice([
            'I do not understand',
            'what are you talking about',
            'do you mind rephrasing that'
        ])
```

I was expecting the bot to at least say it received a message but nothing. What is the problem?

Comment: Why is there no `@` above `async def on_message`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 omg I missed that its working now thanks alot